# symfony event listener preUpdate does get called if one-to-many association changes

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, event-listener

I have an entity that has a `OneToMany` relationship with another entity.

**Meaning entity**

```
/**
 * One Meaning has Many Tags.
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Tag", mappedBy="meaning")
 */
private $tags;
```

**Tag entity**

```
/**
 * Many Tags have One Meaning.
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Meaning", inversedBy="tags")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="meaning_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $meaning;
```

I registered an event listener to the `preUpdate` and `prePersist` doctrine events.

**services.yml**

```
tag.event_listener.meaning_tag_persister:
    class: TagBundle\EventListener\MeaningTagsPersister
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate, method: preUpdate }
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist, method: prePersist }
```

Within this Event Listener all I do is set the `meaning` in the `tag` entity.

**MeaningTagsPersister.php**

```
/**
 * Call before an entity gets updated
 *
 * @param PreUpdateEventArgs $args
 */
public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
{
    /** @var Entry $object */
    $object = $args->getObject();

    if (!$object instanceof Meaning) {
        return;
    }

    /** @var Tag $tag */
    foreach($object->getTags() as $tag) {
        $tag->setMeaning($object);
    }
}
```

The `prePersist` method looks exactly the same. Whenever I create a new `Meaning` entity, the event listener gets called with the appropriate method. When I update the `Meaning` entity the event listener works as well, but only if I update one of its "normal" properties like `name`. If I change any of the `tags` it is not recognized by `doctrine` as a changed entity (which is correct as the `Meaning` entity itself hasn't changed).

Yet, I still have to update the `meaning` within each `Tag` when the `Meaning` entity gets updated. I also have to remove the `meaning` from any `Tag` that is no longer associated with that `Meaning`.

Is an event listener the right way to accomplish this? If yes, how do I get the `Meaning` entity to trigger the `preUpdate` event if only the `tags` have changed? If not, what would be the appropriate way to update all associated `Tag` entities through the `Meaning` entity?

Comment: Did you have  `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()`
 on both entities?

Comment: @ŁukaszD.Tulikowski actually I have that on neither one of the entities. I was under the impression that using event listeners would make this line unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `PreUpdate` does not handle changes on `Associations` as stated in the documentation:

> ...Changes to associations of the updated entity are never allowed in this event, since Doctrine cannot guarantee to correctly handle referential integrity at this point of the flush operation.

[Doctrine#PreUpdate](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate)

To verify, execute the same code in your Controller and it will persist the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You are using doctrine Lifecycle Events you should add

```
/** @Entity @HasLifecycleCallbacks */
```

to your `Meaning` and `Tag` entities.

Refer: [Doctrine Lifecycle Callbacks](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks)

Comment: As I said, i am using an event listener. i am not using callbacks within the entity. adding this line makes no difference. I also mentioned that the events work, but only if I change the properties of the `Meaning`.

Comment: Did you implements the interface use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber; and defined the getSubscribedEvents() method ? 
 https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html